# Avalonia UI - IMultiValueConverter for MultiBinding not firing when a property of an item of a BindingList change

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui

I have an Avalonia UI application where I have 2 BindingList whose items are objects. I'm using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. Here is my viewModel:

```
public partial class DeployViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    [ObservableProperty] private BindingList<ListBoxItemData?>? listScripts = new();
    [ObservableProperty] private BindingList<ListBoxItemData?>? listInstances = new();

    // rest of the code
}
```

the ViewModelBase class implements ObservableObject.

Here is the ListBoxItemData class:

```
public partial class ListBoxItemData : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] private bool isItemChecked;
    [ObservableProperty] private string itemValue;
}
```

I have 2 ListBox on my view whose ItemsSource property are binded to the lists. Here is one of these:

```
<ListBox
    x:Name="ListBoxScripts"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListScripts}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxItemDataTemplate}"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    Height="{Binding $parent.Height}" />
```

So far, everything working.

What I need (and is not working) is to bind the IsEnabled property of a Button to the existence os at least one item on both lists that have the IsItemChecked property == true. For this, I'm trying to use a MultiBinding with a converter.

Here is the DataTemplate used in both ListBoxes:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemDataTemplate" DataType="models:ListBoxItemData">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsItemChecked}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemValue}" />
    </CheckBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here is the Button:

```
<Button
    x:Name="ButtonRunSelectedScripts"
    Content="Run Scripts"
    Click="ButtonRunSelectedScripts_OnClick">
    <Button.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBoolConverter}">
            <Binding Path="ListScripts" />
            <Binding Path="ListInstances" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.IsEnabled>
</Button>
```

I added the reference to the converter to the view resources:

```
<converters:MultiBoolConverter x:Key="MultiBoolConverter" />
```

Here is my converter:

```
public class MultiBoolConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(IList<object?> values, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Count == 2 && values[0] is BindingList<ListBoxItemData> ListScripts &&
            values[0] is BindingList<ListBoxItemData> ListInstances)
        {
            return ListScripts.Any(x => x.IsItemChecked) && ListInstances.Any(x => x.IsItemChecked);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

What is the problem: the converter fires only when I add or remove items on the lists. When the user clicks a checkbox on one of the items (the IsItemChecked property of the item changes to true), the converter is not firing (so the multibinding does not work), even making the lists and their itens as observable objects / properties.  I need to disable the button if no item is selected in both lists, and enable the button if one or more items are selected in both lists.

What am I doing wrong?